# Stuck in boot screen

Tags: windows-10

I was travelling so my PC was unused for a week.  I powered it on today but forgot to choose Windows 10 from the dual boot option so it went in directly to fedora so I restarted it but now I am stuck in bootloop and pressing DEL or F2 key won't enter into Bios setup.

I also tried to reset the power but did not help at all. I have included screenshot below.

What should I do now?

There are few buttons like Start, Reset, MemOK, Keybot, etc. but I have not touched them yet as I am not sure what those buttons will do.

[image: motherboard]

**Boot Screen:**
[image: boot loop]

Comment: probably just need to fix the MBR or bootloader.  Do you remember how you set this up?

Comment: @Nelson I have not done it before. There are many buttons in the motherboard. Do I need to use those buttons? I have updated my question with more details.

Comment: Your computer is setup for dual booting.  Someone must have done this since you probably can't find a vendor who would do this for you... so ask that person for some assistance, because your update shows you have no idea how dual-booting was setup...

Comment: I installed it myself. Before it used to give me a choice between Windows 10 and Fedora. It looks like the 1 TB Western Digital hard drive where I had installed fedora is damaged. I removed that drive and restarted the PC and it went straightly to Windows 10.

Comment: P.s. I'm really glad you'e fully clothed...

Comment: @BigChris You don't know that. All we can see is upper body.